# MSMQ access denied when accessed by IIS .net web service

Tags: iis, msmq

I have a private message queue on machine x that I want to be able to read from/write to from a .NET web service running on IIS 8.5 on machine y. I keep getting

"Access to Message Queuing system is denied"

when calling GetPrivateQueuesByMachine(machine-name)

However I am able to access the same queue using a test console application from machine y. It apparently seems to be a permissions issue, but I have spent hours fiddling with permissions but no luck.

The MSMQ is running as Network Service and I have even unchecked the 'Disable un-authorised RPC calls' for it but that doesn't seem to be the issue because my console application can access the queue.

There is something specific about the .NET web service running in IIS that is resulting in this error but I can't figure it out.

IIS is running as ApplicationPoolIDentity on machine y. The path to the message queue on machine y is in the form: machine-name\private$\private-queue-name

Answer (score 0):

I have finally figured it out. It was to do with the user that my web service was running as. I changed it from Local System to the administrator user and it worked.